# What is the RFC 791 64 octet header?

Tags: ipv4, tcp

I'm trying to understand the PDU sizes as it traverse the TCP/IP model.

RFC 791 says the IP protocol is required to accept datagrams of 576 octets. ( 512 octets, plus up to 64 header octets). I know the IHL (Internet Header Length) field is 4 bits long and specifies the header length in 32 bit words.

So the IP Header has a max size of 60 bytes.... Can someone explain where this 64 octet header comes from and how it differs from the 60 byte header?

Thanks

Comment: The 512+64 bytes were likely the original driver for defining a minimum MTU of 576, but the definite answer to your question is probably lost in time. Note that historical trivia is explicitly off topic here.

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

While there is no 64B header, RFC791's minimum datagram size allows for one. (otherwise there'd be odd power-of-two boundaries.  eg. 64 = 2^6, 60 = 2^6 - 4 - not an even power)

(It's possible there was thinking that zero would equal 16, because IHL==0 would be nonsense. But that was never the case. In fact, IHL will never be less than 5.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply... That makes the most sense out of any answer I've gotten about the subject!